# Illegal reference to net rddata in FIFO

Tags: verilog

The below code is for a FIFO.  It is showing an error as illegal reference to net datatype as `rddata` at line 38 in tb (highlighted by adding a comment "//error line").

Why do I get this error?

```
module fifo(clk,rst,error,empty,full,rddata,wrdata,wr_en,rd_en);

parameter WIDTH = 8;
parameter DEPTH = 16;
input clk,rst,rd_en,wr_en;
input [WIDTH-1:0]wrdata;
output reg [WIDTH-1:0]rddata;
output reg empty,full,error;
reg [WIDTH-1:0]mem[DEPTH-1:0];
reg [3:0]rd_ptr;
reg [3:0]wr_ptr;
reg wr_toggle,rd_toggle;
integer i;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if(rst==1)
    begin
    empty = 1;
    full = 0;
    error = 0;
    rd_ptr = 0;
    wr_ptr = 0;
    wr_toggle = 0;
    rd_toggle = 0;
    for(i=1;i<DEPTH;i=i+1)
    begin
    mem[i] = 0;
    end
end
    else 
        begin
        if(wr_en ==1)begin
        if(full==1)begin
        $display("ERROR:Writing to full FIFO");
        error = 1;
        end

        else
        begin
            mem[wr_ptr] = wrdata;   
            if(wr_ptr == DEPTH-1)begin
            wr_toggle = ~wr_toggle;
            wr_ptr = 0;
            end
            else begin
            wr_ptr = wr_ptr + 1;
            end

        end
        end
        
                if(rd_en ==1)begin
            if(empty==1)begin
                $display("ERROR:REading from EMPTY FIFO");
            error = 1;
            end
        end
        else
        begin
            mem[rd_ptr] = rddata;   
            if(rd_ptr == DEPTH-1)begin
            rd_toggle = ~rd_toggle;
            rd_ptr = 0;
            end
            else begin
            rd_ptr = rd_ptr + 1;
            end
        end
        end

    end
    always@(wr_ptr or rd_ptr)
    begin
        full = 0;
        empty = 0;
        if(wr_ptr == rd_ptr && wr_toggle == rd_toggle)begin
            empty = 1;
            full = 0;
        end
        if(wr_ptr == rd_ptr && wr_toggle != rd_toggle)begin
            empty = 0;
            full = 1;
        end
    

    end
endmodule

//TEST BENCH

`include "fifo.v"
module tbfifo();
parameter WIDTH = 8;
parameter DEPTH = 16;
reg clk,rst,rd_en,wr_en;
reg [WIDTH-1:0]wrdata;
wire [WIDTH-1:0]rddata;
wire empty,full,error;
integer i;

fifo_buff dut (clk,rst,error,empty,full,rddata,wrdata,wr_en,rd_en);
initial
begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;
end


initial
begin
    rst = 1;
    repeat(2) @(posedge clk);
    rst = 0;

    for(i=0;i<DEPTH;i=i+1)begin
    @(posedge clk);
    wr_en = 1;
    wrdata = $random;
    end

    @(posedge clk);
    wr_en = 0;
    wrdata= 0;
    
    for(i=0;i<DEPTH;i=i+1)begin
    @(posedge clk);
    rd_en = 1;
    rddata <= $random;   //error line
    end
    @(posedge clk);
    rd_en = 0;
    
    #100;
    $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`rddata` is an output port of the `fifo_buff` module.  In the testbench, there is a `wire` named `rddata` which connects to the fifo instance.

The problem is that the testbench then tries to drive the signal:

```
rddata <= $random;   //error line
```

That is illegal.  You can not make a procedural assignment (inside an `initial` block, for example) to a `wire`.  And, you should not try to drive that signal from the testbench since it is already driven by the module instance, because that would results in multiple drivers (contention).  You must remove this line.

```
for (i=0; i<DEPTH; i=i+1) begin
    @(posedge clk);
    rd_en = 1;
end
@(posedge clk);
rd_en = 0;
```

Typically, you would monitor an output signal in the testbench (display its value or compare it against a reference model).  This is usually done in a separate process (`always` block, for example) from the input driving process.